# Why redirect PHP get only white page?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm developing in PHP, and I need to change page for different type of user, so I do in this way:

```
switch ($_SESSION['ruolo']) {
                                case 0:
                                    header('Location: ./php/admin/homeAdmin.php');
                                    exit();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    header('Location: ./php/150ore/home150.php');
                                    exit();
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    header('Location: ./php/150ore/home150.php');
                                    exit();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
```

But I obtain only a white page... Without any error..

Why?? Where did I wrong??

EDIT:

I'm not into default case, I cheked it..

This is the page that I wanto redirect:

```
<?php require_once './php/doctype.php'; ?>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        PROVA!!!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: white page => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php usually means syntax errors.

Comment: Add an "echo 'something';" to the "default" case of the switch. I believe the "default" is been executed.

Comment: Go to the page manually. I bet there are errors in that page's script. Or maybe the blank page is the current page and you need to set a `default` for your case

Comment: `switch ($_SESSION['ruolo'])` that doesn't look to be a good way to use a switch/case. You should be checking to see if the session is set. Plus, assigning a variable to that session array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to debug this, there are a couple of things to do:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
switch ($_SESSION['ruolo']) {
    case 0:
        header('Location: ./php/admin/homeAdmin.php');
        exit();
        break;
    case 1:
        header('Location: ./php/150ore/home150.php');
        exit();
        break;
    case 2:
        header('Location: ./php/150ore/home150.php');
        exit();
        break;
    default:
        var_dump("I'm the default case!"); //If you get this, then your session variable is different to 0, 1 or 2.
        break;
}
```

Now, in your `homeAdmin.php` and `home150.php` pages, add at the top:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And see what the errors are saying.

As per your latest edit, i can see that you are using `require_once`, `require` will stop the execution if the given file throws an error, try changing `require_once` to `include_once` in order to check if it works, and also share whats in the `doctype.php` file. Another thing to try is as follows:

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once './php/doctype.php';
?>
```

Comment: I add ini_set but I see nothing... Do I wrong somenthing?? However, I'm not in default case...

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Simply I add an echo.. and if I delete the page to redirect I obtain ...NOT FOUND.....

Comment: Then I believe you should share whats on the pages you are redirecting to.

Comment: @Teo, would you add "echo $_SESSION['ruolo']; " before the switch? Just tell us what is the content of $_SESSION['ruolo'].

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez is 0

Comment: YES.. So stupid.. I write wrong the path into require one... Lost One hour for nothing :( Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[The Location header takes an absolute URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and you seem to be giving a relative file path.

Also, as others have noted, the script may just be failing altogether due to an error elsewhere. Look in the error log.

Comment: *"I think you might also want to get rid of the exit"*  - it should be in there, very important. Otherwise, code may want to continue executing.

Comment: Cleaner to just return, isn't it?

Comment: doesnt matter, just as long something makes it stop.